# Импорт модулей (в этих модулях тоже импорт) на python

Tags: python

Возникла проблема с импортом модулей в python. Есть файловый каталог:[image: Каталог]

Вот код в b.py `import file.c`
Код в a.py `import load.b`. В a.py
выходит ошибка: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file'".
Прошу, помогите решить проблему, я новичëк в python. Решение проблемы найти не смог, заранее спасибо)

Comment: __init__.py куда только не добавлял, увы, не помогло.

Comment: а если добавить его в папку file и написать в нем `imoport c`?

Comment: Shamus Rezol, тогда возникает такая же ошибка ещë и с файлом __init__.py: в файле b.py появляется ошибка "No module named c".

Comment: Попробую использовать sys.path может что и выйдет. Позже сообщу помогло или нет. Всем, кто откликнулся на проблему огромное спасибо! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло следующее, в файл a.py добавил следующие строки:
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], './load'))
Огромное всем спасибо за помощь!  :D[image: Решение моей проблемы]

Answer (score 1):

Измените импорты таким образом

```
# a.py
from load import b

# b.py
from .file import c
```

Comment: Сделал как сказанно. Теперь в a.py нет ошибки. Но она появилась в b.py: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". Ответ отчасти помог. Не могли бы вы пояснить, что я делал не так и что делать теперь?)

Answer (score 0):

### [The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) (docs.python.org)

Интерпретатор ищет нестандартные модули (локальные) в `sys.path`, который он дополнительно расширяет путем директории запуска скрипта. По этой причине, когда он пытается импортировать file в b.py, который запускается через импорт a.py, он не способен найти модуль file. Иными словами, директория test в путях для поиска, а load - нет. Запускаем b.py - load в путях для поиска.

### a.py

Файл можно изменить так:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(sys.argv[0] + "/load")
import load.b
```

То есть мы сами добавляем директорию load в пути поиска модулей.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы натолкнули меня на поиск ответа и я его нашëл! Ваш пример, увы, не подошëл. Как была ошибка, так и осталась. Но я нашëл решение, оно связано с вашим. Ответ выложу отдельно)